# postgres sql returns no row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 followings tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.a
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('a_id_seq'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.b
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('b_id_seq'::regclass),
  fkid bigint,
  CONSTRAINT b_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT b_fkid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (fkid)
      REFERENCES public.a (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE public.history
(

  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('history_id_seq'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT history_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

As you can see, the table A has 1 to many relationship with table B. The `history` table keeps track of logical time inside the app. The following query:

```
WITH main_q AS (
 SELECT 
    a.id
   FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.fkid
)
SELECT main_q.id,
    max(history.id) as as_of
FROM main_q,history
GROUP BY 
    main_q.id
```

Returns no rows, even if tables A contains rows, because History table is empty. However, as soon as I add at least 1 row in history table, the query works.

Could someone please explain how I should modify my query so that it returns rows even if history is empty (as long as table A contains rows) ? I would expect to receive a  `NULL` value in `as_of` column or 0. I tried `COALESCE(max(history.id,0))` but this doesn't work either, well, because no rows in history

**EDIT Example**:

```
Table A content:
id
1
2

Table B content:
id, fkid
1,  2
2,  2

Table History content:
<empty>
```

Comment: Why the cross join in the final select? Sounds as if you are looking for an outer join there as well

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the query below

```
SELECT main_q.id,
    max(history.id) as as_of
FROM main_q,history
GROUP BY 
    main_q.id
```

Why not try a left join, you may have nothing to join, you can try something below

```
SELECT main_q.id,
        max(history.id) as as_of
    FROM main_q left join history on 1=1
    GROUP BY 
        main_q.id
```

Comment: Oh thank you, I didn't think about that... Indeed this works

Comment: Actually I thought about left/right joins only in the context of 1 to many relationships

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you are performing a cartesian product between main_q and history, because you haven't a predicate to join these 2 tables.
Likely, when you are performing this cartesian product, if the second table (history) is empty, the cartesian product returns nothing. As soon as you have 1 record in history, you will get data from Main_q. However, if you have more than 1 record in history, you will start to get duplicate data because of the cartesian product.